# How to set popover view anchor programmatically with Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I was trying to set the presentation of a segue in storyboard to be "Present as popover", and it requires me to add an anchor to it. I have set up a button with code so I could not drag to set the anchor to be that button in storyboard. How can I set the anchor programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A UIPopoverPresentationController which creates a popover needs an anchor point either by specifying it to `barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem?`, a `sourceView: UIView?`, or a `sourceRect:CGRect`.

In your case, you will be applying sourceView: UIView? to the button that you created programatically after initializing your popover...

```
popover.sourceView = myButton
```

Comment: What if there is no popover, but a segue in storyboard?